# How to automate my Junit tests using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline

I implemented some unit and integration tests using JUnit as seen in below (the tests are all in the same class)

```
@Test
    public void shouldReturnThirdOf0UsingClass() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        double actualResult = calculator.doOperation("thirdClass", 0);

        assertThat(actualResult, is(0.0));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnThirdWhenFirstCommandIsAddSecondCommandIsMultiplyAndThirdCommandIsThird() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.doOperation("add",22);
        calculator.doOperation("multiply",7);
        double actualResult = calculator.doOperation("third", 21.0);

        assertThat(actualResult, is(7.0));
    }
```

I am trying to build a pipeline in Jenkins and for that I am adding this task in my gradle.build (with no filter because I want to run all the tests)

```
test{
}
```

In my Jenkins pipeline I am adding this stage "Test". What do I need to add inside the stage to run my tests?

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Test'){
            steps{
            {
        }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Try this `steps { sh 'gradle clean test' }`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to install the [gradle jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle/) to make it quite easy.
After that you can run it like this:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('Test'){
      steps{
        withGradle {
          sh './gradlew test'
        }
      }  
    }
  }

}
```